# Receiving Nonetype error even though I am able to scrape the images of the website,

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I am relatively new to python programming and have written this code to scrape images of website and save it on my computer, although this code seems to work but in the end I am getting a error

```
if len(nametemp)== 0 or nametemp== None:
TypeError: object of type 'NoneType' has no len()
```

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Comment: Don't post code as images. Edit your question and put the code as text (with correct formatting).

Comment: in you `if` statement, swap two expressions, so you check `nametemp== None` first. Python as well as many other programming languages evaluates expressions left to right. So it will attempt to evaluate `len(nametemp) == 0` before proceeding to `nametemp== None` . If `nametemp` is indeed None, as your error message indicates, it fails checking first expression. You can also rewrite your if statement as simple `if not nametemp`. Empty lists and None is falsy: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the order in the if condition,

```
if nametemp == None or len(nametemp) == 0:
```

Comment: This works because if the first condition evaluates to True the second will not be evaluated at all. This makes it so `len` is only called if `nametemp` is not `None`

Comment: @DanishMallick remember to mark the answer if it was helpful,  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235